# How to parse and map multiple fields from 1 excel cell

Tags: json, parsing

[image: Example here]

I've got a CSV parser and the file has multiple strings which I need to map to different fields within one excel cell.

So the example image above I have the postcode, state, and suburb which are all in the same cell - but I need to map these to their respective tables in the database.

How would I do this? The team is saying likely regex, if so what would be the regex I use?

Cheers guys!

I expect each type of data to be split into the relevant data table

Comment: Just a comment, rather than an image I'd suggest you copy the example text into the question. You can mark it up as code. It'll make it easier for people to use it to solve the question and post example answers.

Answer (score 0):

Regex they say? *Then you will have two problems.*

Tackle this with extracting the postcode, then a string split. Here in psuedo code:

```
For i = 1 to lines.Length
string s = lines[i];
string postCode = s[s.Length -4]; // Get postcode
s = s[0, s.Length -4].TrimEnd(); //Remove postcode and trim last space
arr[] = s.Split(" ");  // Split words into array
string state= arr[arr.Length - 1];   //The last word is the state
string suburb; 
  For j = 0 to arr.Length - 1
     suburb += arr[j];
  Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language/framework you're using, but I'm just posting this in vanilla javascript.

The regex I'd use for each cell is:

```js
/([\w\s]+)\s([A-Z]{2,3})\s(\d{4})/
```

Which breaks down into:

1. `([\w\s]+)` capture multiple words or spaces
2. `\s` followed by a space
3. `([A-Z]{2,3})` capture a group of two or three capital letters
4. `\s` followed by a space
5. `(\d{4})` capture four digits

I always find https://www.regexpal.com really useful to write and test my regexes.

Using that in javascript:

```js
const addresses = [
  'Elizabeth Bay NSW 2011',
  'Sydney NSW 2000',
  'St Kilda VIC 3182',
  'Sausage 1234567890',
  'Middle Park QLD 4047',
  'The Big Pineapple QLD 4559',
  'Uluru NT 0872'
]

const reg = /([\w\s]+)\s([A-Z]{2,3})\s(\d{4})/

const matches = addresses.map(address => {
  const match = address.match(reg)
  return match && match.slice(1)
})

console.log(matches)
```

Will give you:

```js
// Matching string, Suburb, State, Postcode
["Elizabeth Bay NSW 2011", "Elizabeth Bay", "NSW", "2011"]
["Sydney NSW 2000", "Sydney", "NSW", "2000"]
["St Kilda VIC 3182", "St Kilda", "VIC", "3182"]
null // The non-matching entry
["Middle Park QLD 4047", "Middle Park", "QLD", "4047"]
["The Big Pineapple QLD 4559", "The Big Pineapple", "QLD", "4559"]
["Uluru NT 0872", "Uluru", "NT", "0872"]
```